# Complex elliptic surface with 24 $I_1$ fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, complex-geometry

Is a complex elliptic surface with 24 $I_1$ fibers always a K3 surface? Is ti possible to characterize a K3 surface in terms of the singular fibers of a given elliptic surface?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. Are you asking whether some version of the first question is true, for some collection of singular fibres of certain types?